# PhoneGap CouchDB to Couchbase syncronization

Tags: cordova, synchronization, couchdb, couchbase

Our database is currently running on CouchDB. Is it possible to sync data between a phonegap 2.9.0 app with a couchbase plugin and our database? It's impossible to find any documentation on this, so I was hoping one of you might know more about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this answer may help:

[Connecting Couchbase sync adapter to couchdb server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792312/connecting-couchbase-sync-adapter-to-couchdb-server)

For CouchDB on android, I still use this:

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Android-Couchbase-Callback

Which is real couchdb running on android. It's heavy and certainly slower than couchbase, but works well for me.