# Connecting Couchbase sync adapter to couchdb server

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

How do I connect the couchbase sync adapter to a couchdb server, the docs only say how to use couchbase server and then to use the "administrator console" which couchdb doesn't have, and when I run

```
sync_adapter -url 192.168.1.xx/mydb
```

it returns an error

Before you say "it can't be done", here is a  quote from the couchbase docs

> "Couchbase Lite can sync with servers running Apache CouchDB and with
>   Couchbase Server via Sync Gateway."

Comment: Just to verify, you are trying to connect the Sync Gateway to a CouchDB server? You can't: it can either be backed by a Walrus file store or Couchbase Server. Why do you want to?

Comment: @Will Then explain this quote from the docs "Couchbase Lite can sync with servers running Apache CouchDB and with Couchbase Server via Sync Gateway."

Answer (score 3):

Couchbase Lite is compatible with CouchDB replication, and you can use it same way as you would use Sync Gateway on top of Couchbase.

What you mixed here is 3 different tools:

1. [Sync Gateway](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads#Couchbase_Mobile), which is actually adapter between [Couchbase Server](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads#Couchbase_Server) and [CouchDB API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/)
2. CouchDB which is another database
3. Couchbase Lite which is mobile database solution

To be more clear, Couchbase Lite is document storage database for mobile platform and from API it totally looks like CouchDB. Since CouchDB has nice and pretty replication algorithm that works over HTTP API (ye, you only need internet connection to make synchronization), authors of Couchbase Lite found it handy and used it.
Next, since Couchbase database uses binary protocol for (instead of HTTP replication) synchronization, they made Sync Gateway for that "HTTP API" sync.

I am not sure if you can replicate Sync Gateway (backed by Walrus or Couchbase) with CouchDB, but for sure you can replicate your Couchbase Lite with Sync Gateway AND/OR with CouchDB.

So long story short:

- CouchDB = database with HTTP API for all operations,
- Couchbase = database, binary protocol (=you need drivers for it),
- Sync Gateway = HTTP API on top Couchbase
- or you can say - Couchbase + Sync Gateway = CouchDB, and
- Couchbase Lite = CouchDB for mobile

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can - note that Couchbase Server is a [significant evolution / fork of CouchDB](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-vs-couchdb), and as such the two now differ significantly.

Would it be possible to change CouchDB to be able to connect to Couchbase Sync Gateway? Possibly, but AFAIK no-one has done that yet.

Comment: Then explain this quote from the docs "Couchbase Lite can sync with servers running Apache CouchDB and with Couchbase Server via Sync Gateway."

Comment: Sync Gateway proxies the Couchbase Server and manages revision information. It is a couch instance and you should be able to replicate against it. I'm working on a [Cordova app](https://github.com/wholcomb/habit_tracker) running Couchbase Lite that I got replicating against CouchDB. I'm in the process of converting it to Couchbase.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization/Replication is inherent in CouchDB.
It has it's own replication protocol. (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html?highlight=replication)

Depending on your application/goal you can sync/replicate directly to CouchDB without using the couchbase sync adapter.

Couchbase lite (both IOS and Android versions) can sync/replicate directly to Couchdb.
Two CouchDB instances can sync/replicate directly to each other.
Pouchdb can sync/replicate directly to other Pouchdb instances or to Couchdb.

You only need the couchbase sync adapter to get couchbase to sync/replicate.

Comment: How exactly? From what I've found couchbase lite only syncs through sync gateway

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/wholcomb/habit_tracker/blob/couchdb-rewrite/www/js/app.js#L124) is some example code that replicates a Couchbase Lite instance with a CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

`sync_gateway -bucket mydb -url http://name:pass@localhost:8092`

Comment: Wait, on this page you have both provided an answer to the question and said "it can't be done" which is it?

Comment: That is how you set up a Sync Gateway to run against Couchbase Server. It doesn't work with CouchDB.